# How to find the specific item from items when using React Select?

Tags: reactjs

```
//value={items.find(x => x.item === selectedValue)}import { Fragment, useState } from //"react";
import Select from 'react-select';

let items = [
    {
        item: 1,
        name: "tv"
    },
    {
        item: 2,
        name: "PC"
    }
]

const Home = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(6)

    const handleChange = obj => {
        setSelectedValue(obj.item)
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>Home page</div>

            <p>Test React Select...</p>
            <Select
                value={items.find(x => x.item === selectedValue)}
                options={items.map(({item, name}) => ({value: name, label: item}))}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />

            <p>selected Value:...</p>
            {selectedValue}

        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide more information, like if you're getting an error.

However, I think your problem is twofold:

1. the `value` of your `Select` component is being set to the entire object instead of the value.
2. You've mixed up the `value` and `label` keys in the `options` prop.

Try this:

```js
            <Select
                value={items.find(x => x.item === selectedValue).item}
                options={items.map(({item, name}) => ({value: item, label: name}))}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

EDIT: You don't need to use `find`, you already have this value:

```js
            <Select
                value={selectedValue}
                options={items.map(({item, name}) => ({value: item, label: name}))}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
```